# ... "through thick and thin", which is which?

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning, phrase-origin

When they say, they'll be with you *"[through thick and thin](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/through-thick-and-thin)"*, which one of these two is the tough one to test your relationship and which is the rosy one?

> If you support or stay with someone *through thick and thin*, you always support or stay with them, even if there are problems or difficulties
>   (C.D)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The phrase originated as 'through thicket and thin wood', which was a
>   straightforward literal description of any determined progress through
>   the 'thick' English countryside.
>   http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/through-thick-and-thin.html
>
> When used in a metaphorical, rather than literal, sense, the “thick”
>   part of this idiom is meant to reflect difficulties, while the “thin”
>   part encompasses the easier parts of life.
>   http://www.wisegeek.com/what-are-the-origins-of-the-phrase-through-thick-and-thin.htm

Answer (score 3):

The original idiom was ["through thicket and thin wood"](https://books.google.com/books?id=wrNlquCOhXkC&pg=PT120).

A thicket is a densely wooded area, so it's naturally harder to get through than a "thin wood". So "thick" would be the hard times.